# How to add custom codes to HTTPStatus in Python 3.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

My HTTP client uses the Python *requests* library to access an API proxied by CloudFlare. The client converts the numerical response status code to an `HTTPStatus` enum instance. Simplified ...

```
import requests
from http import HTTPStatus

url = ...
response = requests.get(url)
status = HTTPStatus(response.status_code)
```

The CloudFlare proxy service can return some unofficial 5xx HTTP status codes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#CloudFlare. These cause `HTTPStatus` to raise a `ValueError` because codes such as 522 (Connection Timed Out) are not members of the `HTTPStatus` enum defined in Python's `lib/http/__init__.py`.

How can I add the unoffical CloudFlare status codes to the `HTTPStatus` enum? Or, how can I load the `HTTPStatus` enum members into some other enum along with the unoffical CloudFlare status codes?

The Python 3.5 `Enum` documentation, https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html, describes restrictions that have thwarted me thus far.

> Section 8.13.9: Subclassing an enumeration is allowed only if the
>   enumeration does not define any members.
>
> Section 8.13.14.2: The most interesting thing about `Enum` members is
>   that they are singletons. `EnumMeta` creates them all while it is
>   creating the `Enum` class itself, and then puts a custom `__new__()`
>   in place to ensure that no new ones are ever instantiated by returning
>   only the existing member instances.

Comment: Do you absolutely _need_ to use `HTTPStatus`? The fact that it isn't mutable makes it pretty much impossible to change. You could just create a dictionary mapping status codes to statii instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new [aenum library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)<sup>1</sup> has an `extend_enum` function that is capable of adding new members to an existing enumeration.

Example usage:

```
import aenum
from http import HTTPStatus

aenum.extend_enum(HTTPStatus, 'BAD_SPAM', 513, 'Too greasy')
aenum.extend_enum(HTTPStatus, 'BAD_EGGS', 514, 'Too green')
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: @joelsphrentz:  Thanks for the edit, I fixed the quoting.