# Best way to extend HTTPStatus with custom value

Tags: python-3.x, enums

I am extending `HTTPStatus` with a custom value:

```
from http import HTTPStatus

HTTPStatus.MY_CUSTOM_SERVICE_TIMEOUT = 573
```

I am wondering why I do not see that value when inspecting `HTTPStatus`:

```
>>> dir(HTTPStatus)
['ACCEPTED', 'ALREADY_REPORTED', 'BAD_GATEWAY', 'BAD_REQUEST', 'CONFLICT', 'CONTINUE', 'CREATED', 'EXPECTATION_FAILED', 'FAILED_DEPENDENCY', 'FORBIDDEN', 'FOUND', 'GATEWAY_TIMEOUT', 'GONE', 'HTTP_VERSION_NOT_SUPPORTED', 'IM_USED', 'INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE', 'INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR', 'LENGTH_REQUIRED', 'LOCKED', 'LOOP_DETECTED', 'METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED', 'MOVED_PERMANENTLY', 'MULTIPLE_CHOICES', 'MULTI_STATUS', 'NETWORK_AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED', 'NON_AUTHORITATIVE_INFORMATION', 'NOT_ACCEPTABLE', 'NOT_EXTENDED', 'NOT_FOUND', 'NOT_IMPLEMENTED', 'NOT_MODIFIED', 'NO_CONTENT', 'OK', 'PARTIAL_CONTENT', 'PAYMENT_REQUIRED', 'PERMANENT_REDIRECT', 'PRECONDITION_FAILED', 'PRECONDITION_REQUIRED', 'PROCESSING', 'PROXY_AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED', 'REQUESTED_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE', 'REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE', 'REQUEST_HEADER_FIELDS_TOO_LARGE', 'REQUEST_TIMEOUT', 'REQUEST_URI_TOO_LONG', 'RESET_CONTENT', 'SEE_OTHER', 'SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE', 'SWITCHING_PROTOCOLS', 'TEMPORARY_REDIRECT', 'TOO_MANY_REQUESTS', 'UNAUTHORIZED', 'UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY', 'UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE', 'UPGRADE_REQUIRED', 'USE_PROXY', 'VARIANT_ALSO_NEGOTIATES', '__class__', '__doc__', '__members__', '__module__']
```

The value itself is available:

```
>>> HTTPStatus.MY_CUSTOM_SERVICE_TIMEOUT
573
```

Is there something strange going on? Should I approach this differently?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add custom codes to HTTPStatus in Python 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36907242/how-to-add-custom-codes-to-httpstatus-in-python-3-5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `http.HTTPStatus` is an `Enum` and Python doesn't really, trully have `Enum` as a generic type (which is why you can do what you're doing - languages that actually recognize `Enum` as something special wouldn't let you mess with it like this in general). Of course, Python does its best to make `Enums` behave as they should (immutable, iterable, mappable...).

There is actually a `collections.OrderedDict` underneath (`Enum._member_map_`) that gets created when you create a new `Enum` type - it reads in the members, aliases the duplicates and adds an additional `value -> enum member` map as `Enum._value2member_map_` (all of that is done by the `enum.EnumMeta` metaclass). When you `dir()` an enum - you get that map (or more precisely, the enum names list available in the `Enum._member_names_` list) and any changes you may have applied at runtime doesn't count (otherwise it wouldn't be immutable). In other words, when you do `HTTPStatus.MY_CUSTOM_SERVICE_TIMEOUT = 573` you're not extending the `Enum`, you're just adding a dynamic property to the `Enum` object in question.

You should extend your `Enum` types the regular, OOP way if you want to add custom members... except Python won't let you do this either. So if you really insist doing it run-time you can, kind of, hack the internal structure to make Python believe your enum value was there all along:

```
# HERE BE DRAGONS!
# DO NOT do this unless you absolutely have to.

from http import HTTPStatus

def add_http_status(name, value, phrase, description=''):
    # call our new member factory, it's essentially the `HTTPStatus.__new__` method
    new_status = HTTPStatus.__new_member__(HTTPStatus, value, phrase, description)
    new_status._name_ = name  # store the enum's member internal name
    new_status.__objclass__ = HTTPStatus.__class__  # store the enum's member parent class
    setattr(HTTPStatus, name, new_status)  # add it to the global HTTPStatus namespace
    HTTPStatus._member_map_[name] = new_status  #  add it to the name=>member map
    HTTPStatus._member_names_.append(name)  # append the names so it appears in __members__
    HTTPStatus._value2member_map_[value] = new_status  # add it to the value=>member map
```

And now you can 'really' extend the `HTTPStatus` at runtime:

```
try:
    print(HTTPStatus(573))
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
print("MY_CUSTOM_SERVICE_TIMEOUT" in dir(HTTPStatus))
add_http_status("MY_CUSTOM_SERVICE_TIMEOUT", 573, "Custom service timeout")
print("MY_CUSTOM_SERVICE_TIMEOUT" in dir(HTTPStatus))
print(HTTPStatus(573))
print(HTTPStatus.MY_CUSTOM_SERVICE_TIMEOUT.value)
print(HTTPStatus(573).phrase)
```

Which will give you:

```
573 is not a valid HTTPStatus
False
True
HTTPStatus.MY_CUSTOM_SERVICE_TIMEOUT
573
Custom service timeout
```

Keep in mind that this code doesn't handle aliasing, de-duplication and other nice things that you should absolutely be doing if you want to arbitrary extend an `Enum` so don't use duplicate or invalid values or you'll break it (in a sense it won't work as expected afterwards). Check the additional steps taken in `enum.EnumMeta.__new__()` to ensure its validity.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. The reason why I wanted to extend runtime is because I have no way of telling all modules that are importing HTTPStatus to actually import my derived class.

Comment: Nice answer.  But use `'aenum.extend_enum` instead of writing your own.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `extend_enum` function from the [`aenum library`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)<sup>1</sup>:

```
import aenum
import http

aenum.extend_enum(http.HTTPStatus, 'CustomTimeout', 537, 'more helpful phrase here')
```

Which results in:

```
>>> list(http.HTTPStatus)
[<HTTPStatus.CONTINUE: 100>,
...,
<HTTPStatus.CustomTimeout: 537>]
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: Great, thanks! Sine this approach uses a runtime extension to the HTTPStatus, it means it would be visible to all modules making use of `http.HTTPStatus`, even those importing it before the extension is performed, correct?

Comment: @dangonfast:  Correct.